# Javascript time won't print out (date.js)

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have the following code using date.js:

```
                <div id="Timer">
                    <script>Date.parse("hh:mm");</script> 
                    <div class="Timers">

                        <div class="timerSpace"><span style="text-align: left; color: #DDDD11;">Hours from now</span></div>
                        <div class="timer1"><span style="color: #FFFF11;"><script>var d1 = date.parse(Date.today().addHours(6.0)); document.write(d1);</script><span></div>
                        <div class="timer2"><span style="color: #FFFF11;"><script>var d2 = date.parse(Date.today().addHours(12.0)); document.write(d2);</script><span></div>
                        <div class="timer3"><span style="color: #FFFF11;"><script>var d3 = date.parse(Date.today().addHours(18.0));document.write(d3);</script><span></div>
                        <div class="timer4"><span style="color: #FFFF11;"><script>var d4 = date.parse(Date.today().addHours(24.0));document.write(d4);</script><span></div>
                        <div class="timerSpace"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And I'm not getting anything printed onto my page?  Why?

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console for any errors?

Comment: What is Date.parse("hh:mm")?? there is no date that can be parsed in there, nor does it assign it to a variable that can be used. Are you using a library, or have you extended the Date function? javascript does not recognize .today(), .addHours(), only setDate(getDate(d) + x);

Comment: date.js is the library which has both date.parse and the function that you parse it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse` is used to parse an existing `String` into a `Date` object. Use `toString()` instead:

```
Date.today().toString("hh:mm")
```

Also, use `document.write` to write to the document, that is:

```
<script>document.write(Date.today().toString("hh:mm"))</script>
```

Comment: I have no idea why this isn't working right....

Comment: var d1 = new Date();
                                d1.setHours(d1.getHours() + 6 );
                                document.write(d1.toTimeString());​
                                </script><span></div>

Comment: @Damien.Bell: What is the output you expect? Can you please modify this demo with your code http://jsfiddle.net/XHKqP/?

Comment: Updated:  http://jsfiddle.net/XHKqP/1/

Comment: @Damien.Bell: You can't specify a `<script>` with a `src` and put code inside it. If you need to include `date.js` do it in a separate `<script>` block. http://jsfiddle.net/XHKqP/3/

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
var d1 = date.parse(Date.today().addHours(6.0));
```

try

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.setHours( d1.getHours() + 6 );
document.write( d1.toTimeString() );​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P5RL6/

Comment: Not sure why this isn't working...

<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js">
                                    var d4 = new Date();
                                    d4.setHours(d4.getHours()+timer);
                                    document.write(d4.toString());​
                                </script>

Comment: what is your timer var set to? http://jsfiddle.net/P5RL6/1/